# UITabBarController as a delegate of its sub view controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, interface-builder

I currently have a Storyboard with a subclass of UITabBarController linked to 3 view controllers.
Those view controllers are custom subclasses of UIViewController, and I added a "delegate" property, as I need to access a property (settings) from the main view controller (retrieved from a .plist file).
It's a Settings class that handle reading and writing from/to this file.

Anyway, I haven't found how to set their delegate property from IB, so I added this in the code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /* Fetch settings */
    NSString* settingsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"plist"];   // Load settings from file
    settings = [[Settings alloc] initWithContentOfFile:settingsPath];

    for (UIViewController<HasDelegate> *c in [self viewControllers]) {
        c.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

But only the 1st view controller (the one that is displayed when starting the app) can access it.
The other ones has a nil pointer for the delegate property.

Is it the right way to do it ?
What am I missing ?

Comment: When you are iterating through `[self viewControllers]` do you actually get all 3 of your view controllers, or do you only end up retrieving one?

Comment: Actually, it seems I retrieve each one. I added `NSLog(@"%@", c.title);` And it prints them. I can reread `c.delegate` and it points to `self`. BUT when I check `c`'s address, it is not the same than when I am in the `loadView` for the 2nd and 3rd view controller.

Comment: Do you do anything weird when transitioning between VCs in the tab bar controller?  Or do you simply use the native standard behavior

Comment: I use native behavior, and I just tap the tabs on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was accessing the UINavigationController, instead of its rootViewController. I added :

```
if([c isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    NSLog(@"UINavigationController");
    UINavigationController *navC = (UINavigationController*)c;
    [[[navC viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self];
}
```

and it works like a charm !